# jQuery templates to dynamically render image from a tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

In my template I have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li>${members_pics['0']}</li>
    <li>${members_pics['1']}</li>
</ul>
```

The `members_pics` attribute holds this value:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/parce/sites/default/files/styles/profile_picture/public/pictures/picture-1-1316209044.jpg" alt="" />
```

When the script process, instead of getting the actual image being rendered on my page, it prints the value above as a string.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
Here is my jquery code:

```
    searchBut.click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: queryURL,
           data: "country="+countryInput.val(),
           success: function(result){

             searchResults = JSON.parse(result);

             console.log(searchResults);

             jQuery.each(searchResults,function(index){
                this.field_city = this.field_city.und["0"].value;
                 [..]

             });

             jQuery('#parceSearchTpl').tmpl(searchResults).appendTo(searchWarper);  
           }
         });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image tag is being HTML encoded.

You should change your template like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{html members_pics['0']}}</li>
    <li>{{html members_pics['1']}}</li>
</ul>
```

That will output the raw string. If the string is coming from untrusted sources, this could leave your site vulnerable to XSS attacks though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though after trying it i get the following error in FB: **missing ) in parenthetical**

Answer (score -2):

I can think of two solutions to your question (if I'm understanding it correctly)

- doing `new Image(...)` on your result.
- Testing images from `localhost` in your browser is unlikely to work. Run a local server to test with

Comment: How childish is that.. Downvoted me for what reason ? I am sorry man but what you said didn't make anysense